# I'm getting null when I try to access firebase children objects with a variable

Tags: javascript, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to access objects in Firebase from a React Native app based on the user that submitted them. To this end, I want to use a variable that contains the user id so that the correct user can access the correct objects. However, when I use the variable, the object returned to me is null.

I've already tried entering a user string directly into the argument and that worked, so I know the data can be reached this way, but is no good for when another user wants to access the data.

export default class WeekViewer extends React.Component {

```
componentDidMount(){
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
      if (user) {
        userID = user.uid;
        console.log(userID);

      } else {
        // No user is signed in.
      }
    });
```

the problem lies here
userID prints the correct ID but when entered as the argument it does not work
I have also tried .child(), it makes no difference
however if I enter a string which is the ID it works.
I cannot figure out why

```
    db.ref('/week/' + userID).on('value', (data) => {
    console.log(userID)
    console.log(data.toJSON());

});
```

I am hoping to print the data to the console so that I will be able to move on and start using the data in my application.

Comment: onAuthStateChanged is asynchronous. If you trying to access/listen to the ref prior to onAuthStateChanged has successfully resolved, it will be undefined and cause the error. Are you checking that userID is valid/truthy prior to trying to access the ref?

Comment: I just tried to print it before using it as an argument and it is undefined.
I'm not very experienced with React Native/Javascript. Any  suggestions on how to get it to wait for resolution?

Comment: Edit, when I got my head back together, I put the retrieval code into a method and printed it. It works wonderfully, thanks for the help!

Comment: Sounds like an answer @AlexanderStaroselsky! :)